# How do i access the steeringTarget after the current steeringTarget?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting

I'm raycasting a ray from the agent in the direction of the steeringTarget with a specific length. If it reaches the steeringTarget i want to cast another ray with the remaing length towards the next one. I'm doing this to predict the position of enemies in a tower defense game which i will launch a projectile towards.

Comment: Please post the code you have until now and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have to do is access the agents paths corners and store it in a Vector3 list.